# Why does SSL handshaking sometimes kill my CPU?

Tags: java, security, ssl, https, bouncycastle

We are running in to a very strange problem: we're using a modified version of the [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) HTTP proxy (more akin to the [BrowserMob Proxy](https://github.com/webmetrics/browsermob-proxy)) and finding that in some circumstances, which we can't reliably reproduce, CPU grinds to a halt when handling SSL connections.

A stack dump reveals that that the thread gets either stuck here:

```
"ProxyHandler$SslRelay3-1" prio=10 tid=0x09f9a400 nid=0x81f runnable [0xb2e69000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.math.BigInteger.multiply(BigInteger.java:1144)
    at java.math.BigInteger.lucasLehmerSequence(BigInteger.java:820)
    at java.math.BigInteger.passesLucasLehmer(BigInteger.java:750)
    at java.math.BigInteger.primeToCertainty(BigInteger.java:730)
    at java.math.BitSieve.retrieve(BitSieve.java:188)
    at java.math.BigInteger.largePrime(BigInteger.java:606)
    at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:511)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.DHParametersHelper.generateSafePrimes(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.DHParametersGenerator.generateParameters(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.dh.KeyPairGeneratorSpi.generateKeyPair(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DHCrypt.<init>(DHCrypt.java:76)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ServerHandshaker.setupEphemeralDHKeys(ServerHandshaker.java:797)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ServerHandshaker.trySetCipherSuite(ServerHandshaker.java:702)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ServerHandshaker.chooseCipherSuite(ServerHandshaker.java:633)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(ServerHandshaker.java:425)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:139)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:516)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:454)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
    - locked <0x8a18f238> (a com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl)
    - locked <0x8a18f2c0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1112)
    - locked <0x8a18f2c8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:744)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
    - locked <0x8a18f300> (a com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.LineInput.fill(LineInput.java:477)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.LineInput.fillLine(LineInput.java:555)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.LineInput.readLineBuffer(LineInput.java:301)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.LineInput.readLineBuffer(LineInput.java:285)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpRequest.readHeader(HttpRequest.java:239)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.readRequest(HttpConnection.java:866)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:912)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)
```

Multiple stack dumps reveal that generateSafePrimes() is continually running and each subsequent stack dump shows slightly different places in java.math.BigInteger that is running. However, it's hard to tell where exactly things are getting stuck or if there is a legit infinite loop (I doubt it though).

Investigating further, I was able to capture the relevant output with -Djavax.net.debug=ssl set, for both a *working* example and a *broken* example.

When things work, the handshaking happens almost instantly and we see this debug output, resulting in a proper Diffie-Hellman key exchange:

```
ProxyHandler$SslRelay3-9, setSoTimeout(10000) called
ProxyHandler$SslRelay3-9, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 171
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1320359479 bytes = { 176, 253, 143, 106, 114, 151, 90, 1, 9, 53, 221, 254, 160, 42, 176, 239, 1, 222, 180, 41, 56, 115, 203, 185, 74, 68, 2, 27 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [Unknown 0x0:0xff, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0x0:0x88, Unknown 0x0:0x87, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0x0:0x84, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0x0:0x45, Unknown 0x0:0x44, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0x0:0x96, Unknown 0x0:0x41, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Unsupported extension server_name, [host_name: REDACTED]
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Unsupported extension type_35, data: 
***
%% Created:  [Session-10, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1320359480 bytes = { 85, 189, 191, 119, 135, 205, 134, 161, 254, 164, 83, 102, 9, 149, 182, 59, 83, 201, 110, 233, 114, 168, 166, 192, 80, 250, 204, 121 }
Session ID:  {79, 179, 22, 56, 209, 63, 115, 246, 134, 192, 16, 222, 203, 184, 204, 251, 145, 49, 200, 163, 218, 68, 78, 13, 96, 106, 79, 11, 93, 61, 187, 48}
Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
***
Cipher suite:  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=REDACTED, OU=Test, O=CyberVillainsCA, L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  RSA Public Key
            modulus: 9fff00e7f363191e3d3dc0aa85a2791776ecab2d8365ab4026a5e051ff60b6ce11e484a6279f5e123559dfa44479797c7b04a97d1bcfa0e10479d616deeb48cd5c40890041786106a4e88b365585113b107a80be9b3bdf19672a3ffb40a7fac583cae69d262bad1a74ce888f84643733affdbd4f939178eb060f3a32a34345d7
    public exponent: 10001

  Validity: [From: Sun May 22 02:45:42 UTC 2011,
               To: Thu Apr 20 02:45:42 UTC 2017]
  Issuer: C=US, OU=CyberVillians Certification Authority, O=CyberVillians.com
  SerialNumber: [    01375389 64a8]

Certificate Extensions: 5
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: D1 6A D0 8E B2 7E B4 90   C3 7C 30 D1 5B F2 70 71  .j........0.[.pq
0010: 94 B4 3F A8                                        ..?.
]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 0A BC 17 95 34 6B BC 87   1B 5B 4C FD F5 63 85 2D  ....4k...[L..c.-
0010: B4 8F F5 6C                                        ...l
]

]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://127.0.0.1:4444/selenium-server/sslSupport/blank_crl.pem]
]]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
  clientAuth
  2.16.840.1.113730.4.1
  1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.3
]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 13 CA C0 80 2D BE AC 9D   3F 58 EF A9 C9 C4 E3 43  ....-...?X.....C
0010: FE ED 5A 14 0A 04 6B 67   ED 19 EF 8D C2 14 53 6D  ..Z...kg......Sm
0020: 1A 3F B8 99 8E 2B B1 0F   50 83 F1 5A 56 43 5F 8B  .?...+..P..ZVC_.
0030: 8B 0A EE 98 04 D7 32 FC   B9 FE 43 57 97 0B FC 46  ......2...CW...F
0040: 02 4E A4 8F F3 F0 65 BD   20 28 76 DB 29 16 B6 16  .N....e. (v.)...
0050: 3B 57 D3 B3 24 21 C5 AC   64 8E 95 C9 92 06 DC 95  ;W..$!..d.......
0060: F8 B4 62 74 8C 44 8D 96   83 94 0F 5C EE B0 A4 8B  ..bt.D.....\....
0070: 5A EA 1E 58 B2 A3 8B 0E   E1 79 5F 06 BF EE E3 A9  Z..X.....y_.....

]
***
*** Diffie-Hellman ServerKeyExchange
DH Modulus:  { 189, 165, 218, 21, 118, 110, 155, 89, 53, 21, 128, 88, 254, 47, 40, 106, 51, 167, 219, 167, 68, 153, 230, 233, 63, 125, 198, 5, 12, 230, 7, 156, 21, 89, 142, 17, 146, 200, 33, 197, 86, 116, 41, 212, 22, 176, 162, 138, 121, 124, 107, 57, 27, 209, 42, 131, 182, 254, 178, 211, 86, 112, 32, 222, 185, 43, 212, 180, 71, 200, 174, 22, 11, 172, 213, 135, 217, 124, 40, 120, 218, 170, 182, 151, 131, 89, 191, 59, 214, 52, 56, 119, 212, 5, 163, 107 }
DH Base:  { 173, 84, 126, 57, 69, 157, 241, 124, 0, 60, 149, 36, 136, 75, 82, 91, 142, 16, 240, 117, 1, 146, 23, 25, 218, 139, 127, 216, 27, 183, 252, 214, 189, 253, 2, 42, 125, 1, 73, 84, 49, 69, 80, 239, 179, 134, 236, 96, 175, 244, 36, 206, 203, 163, 251, 64, 83, 253, 74, 94, 114, 248, 210, 145, 130, 225, 252, 33, 56, 100, 6, 53, 163, 138, 154, 7, 142, 209, 10, 230, 107, 233, 77, 189, 151, 46, 115, 77, 93, 57, 47, 178, 121, 240, 183, 255 }
Server DH Public Key:  { 36, 153, 18, 99, 95, 39, 135, 103, 245, 21, 20, 161, 159, 246, 67, 6, 183, 101, 8, 62, 161, 21, 211, 95, 193, 13, 248, 152, 101, 138, 143, 247, 29, 176, 255, 165, 78, 140, 108, 243, 219, 222, 59, 181, 4, 71, 51, 164, 1, 80, 97, 70, 66, 189, 175, 19, 248, 11, 77, 84, 112, 134, 139, 222, 81, 12, 45, 173, 173, 102, 141, 195, 80, 244, 20, 251, 109, 246, 24, 194, 140, 201, 29, 251, 26, 191, 9, 201, 45, 107, 59, 28, 148, 25, 220, 215 }
Signed with a DSA or RSA public key
*** ServerHelloDone
ProxyHandler$SslRelay3-9, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 1332
```

However, when things are broken things are very different and we never even get to attempt the DH exchange:

```
ProxyHandler$SslRelay3-1, setSoTimeout(10000) called
ProxyHandler$SslRelay3-1, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 171
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1320358903 bytes = { 148, 198, 81, 98, 2, 66, 235, 221, 74, 170, 130, 205, 43, 139, 18, 60, 121, 148, 234, 153, 3, 89, 48, 153, 168, 196, 80, 54 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [Unknown 0x0:0xff, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0x0:0x88, Unknown 0x0:0x87, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0x0:0x84, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0x0:0x45, Unknown 0x0:0x44, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0x0:0x96, Unknown 0x0:0x41, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Unsupported extension server_name, [host_name: REDACTED]
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Unsupported extension type_35, data: 
***
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
INFO 05/16 02:46:23 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Reported 0 slices representing 0 transactions
INFO 05/16 02:46:23 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Collected 0 transactions
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
INFO 05/16 02:46:33 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Reported 0 slices representing 0 transactions
INFO 05/16 02:46:33 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Collected 0 transactions
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
INFO 05/16 02:46:43 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Reported 0 slices representing 0 transactions
INFO 05/16 02:46:43 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Collected 0 transactions
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
INFO 05/16 02:46:53 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Reported 0 slices representing 0 transactions
INFO 05/16 02:46:53 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Collected 0 transactions
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
INFO 05/16 02:47:03 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Reported 0 slices representing 0 transactions
INFO 05/16 02:47:03 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Collected 0 transactions
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
Acceptor [SSL: ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=35182]], setSoTimeout(10000) called
ProxyHandler$SslRelay2-0, setSoTimeout(10000) called
ProxyHandler$SslRelay2-0, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 165
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1320359212 bytes = { 59, 24, 42, 178, 241, 201, 150, 61, 101, 15, 153, 40, 167, 176, 22, 250, 205, 245, 89, 8, 156, 34, 122, 161, 4, 99, 40, 108 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [Unknown 0x0:0xff, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0x0:0x88, Unknown 0x0:0x87, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0x0:0x84, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0x0:0x45, Unknown 0x0:0x44, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0x0:0x96, Unknown 0x0:0x41, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Unsupported extension server_name, [host_name: sb-ssl.google.com]
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Unsupported extension type_35, data: 
***
Acceptor [SSL: ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=53331]], setSoTimeout(10000) called
ProxyHandler$SslRelay3-0, setSoTimeout(10000) called
ProxyHandler$SslRelay3-0, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 171
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1320359212 bytes = { 124, 252, 208, 200, 213, 33, 188, 186, 19, 175, 247, 227, 126, 10, 57, 66, 29, 66, 230, 145, 66, 28, 210, 98, 167, 31, 240, 85 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [Unknown 0x0:0xff, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0x0:0x88, Unknown 0x0:0x87, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0x0:0x84, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0x0:0x45, Unknown 0x0:0x44, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0x0:0x96, Unknown 0x0:0x41, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Unsupported extension server_name, [host_name: REDACTED]
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Unsupported extension type_35, data: 
***
INFO 05/16 02:47:13 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Reported 0 slices representing 0 transactions
INFO 05/16 02:47:13 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Collected 0 transactions
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
INFO 05/16 02:47:23 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Reported 0 slices representing 0 transactions
INFO 05/16 02:47:23 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Collected 0 transactions
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
INFO 05/16 02:47:33 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Reported 0 slices representing 0 transactions
INFO 05/16 02:47:33 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Collected 0 transactions
INFO 05/16 02:47:43 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Reported 0 slices representing 0 transactions
INFO 05/16 02:47:43 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Collected 0 transactions
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
INFO 05/16 02:47:53 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Reported 0 slices representing 0 transactions
INFO 05/16 02:47:53 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Collected 0 transactions
INFO 05/16 02:48:03 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Reported 0 slices representing 0 transactions
INFO 05/16 02:48:03 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Collected 0 transactions
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
INFO 05/16 02:48:13 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Reported 0 slices representing 0 transactions
INFO 05/16 02:48:13 b.n.w.a.LoadTestTra~ - Collected 0 transactions
INFO 05/16 02:48:14 o.o.s.s.SeleniumDri~ - Got result: Timed out after 120000ms on session 5a7b389b01c041fcb3632c2f5056043b
```

That log spans a time range of 2 minutes, in which almost nothing happens. There is some additional SSL logging related to sb-ssl.google.com (which also blocks), but that can be ignored - it's just the Firefox browser checking in to [Google's safe browsing API](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/).

I should note: similar [complaints](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3498) had been levied against the Selenium proxy about a month ago, but they were [resolved](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=16442) by upgrading to the latest version of BouncyCastle. However, we are finding that the problem *occasionally* still happens and we can't figure out why.

I'm hoping the StackOverflow family can shed some light on why sometimes the thread gets stuck in *org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.DHParametersHelper.generateSafePrimes* and other times the logging shows that we proceed directly to this key line right away:

```
%% Created:  [Session-10, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
```

Thanks for any insight!

Edit: I should add that we're using Java 1.6.0_18-b07 on Linux (32bit and 64bit are affected), Selenium 2.21, and BouncyCastle 1.47.

Edit #2: I just confirmed that this problem doesn't exist when using Java 7.

Comment: Can you run this with Selenium -debug flag?

Comment: @Krroae27 unfortunately, no. We don't exactly use the standalone Selenium, so there is no command line arg. What would you expect to find using the -debug flag? If I have a better idea of what you're looking for I might be able to get similar logging using a different technique.

Comment: I've definitely found something I don't like but I am doing a little more research. https://gist.github.com/2707498

Comment: @Krroae27 Definitely sounds a bit like this: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.encryption.bouncy-castle.devel/7016. The question is: why do we sometimes get through unharmed and other times get totally hosed :P

Comment: How much load is your server under? As running my test script with 10 threads absolutely destroys my i7-970 @ 3.2.... To answer your question it's luck.. Sometimes the primes only takes 21 but I've had highs of 3.2k....

Comment: @Krroae27 the load is extremely heavy - makes the computer almost unusable. But I'm not sure it's just luck. It seems to be that there might be some race condition that causes the need for the generateSafePrimes sometimes and not others. It may be how the Selenium proxy interacts with BC...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11293/discussion-between-krroae27-and-patrick-lightbody)

Comment: i read the chat and don't understand what you guys think is wrong.  the bc code in the gist looked fine to me - why do you think it bad?  isn't the problem likely a bug in the big decimal probable prime code if it works in 7 but not in 6?  or a bad certainty value that's handled better in 7?

Comment: @andrewcooke You're right - I don't necessary believe that the code that krroae27 linked to in gist is bad. Check out the comment on this JIRA ticket: http://www.bouncycastle.org/jira/browse/BJA-19. I believe the real issue is that sometimes we try to generate a key using DH without parameters, and sometimes we don't. I think that is the crux.

Comment: @Krroae27 jdk-7u4-linux-i586 and jdk-7u4-linux-x64 did the trick.

Comment: @PatrickLightbody did you ever get a chance to reproduce the issue with debug all on? I understand that for some reason Java 7 has fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

So check the full comment thread, but basically after a lot of debugging I discovered that upgrading to Java 7 resolved the issue. Not sure what the original issue was with Java 6, but we're just going to go ahead with Java 7. I hope this helps someone in the future!